Using LINQ Projection to fetch deeply nested properties
The logs i get :
Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync


The problem description:
I am trying to write a query to fetch some order details along with their products (which have color,dimension ,etc ). I am using projection but i need to access some deeply nested properties to get the price per dimension.
UPDATE: This is where i fetch all the data from the join table
 var allProductsWithDimensions = await productsOnDimensionsRepository.GetAllAsync();

This is the query that i wrote:

var allProductsOnCurrentOrder = await productsOnOrdersRepository
                .FindQueryable(pc => pc.IdComanda == order.IdComandaDto)
                .Select(pc => new ProductsOnOrdersDto
                {
                    IdProdusDto = pc.Produs.IdProdus,
                    CodProdusDto = pc.Produs.CodProdus,
                    NumeProdusDto = pc.Produs.NumeProdus!,
                    PretBazaProdusDto = pc.Produs.PretDeBaza,
                    NumeProducatorDto = pc.Produs.Producator == null ? null : pc.Produs.Producator.NumeProducator,
                    TipulProdusuluiDto = pc.Produs.TipulProdusului,
                    NumeSetDto = pc.Set == null ? null : pc.Set.NumeSet,
                    PretSetDto = pc.Set == null ? null : pc.Set.PretSet,
                    PretRedusSetDto = pc.Set == null ? null : pc.Set.PretRedusSet,
                    NumeCuloareDto = pc.PcCuloare.NumeCuloare,
                    CodCuloareDto = pc.PcCuloare.CodCuloare.CodCuloare!,
                    LungimeDto = pc.PcDimensiune == null ? null : pc.PcDimensiune.Lungime,
                    LatimeDto = pc.PcDimensiune == null ? null : pc.PcDimensiune.Latime,
                    RecomandarePatDto = pc.PcDimensiune == null ? null : pc.PcDimensiune.RecomandarePat,
                    PretDto = pc.PcDimensiune == null
                        ? null
                        : (from pcd in allProductsWithDimensions
                            where pcd.IdProdus == pc.Produs.IdProdus && pcd.IdDimensiune == pc.PcDimensiune.IdDimensiune
                            select pcd.Pret).First(),
                    PretRedusDto = pc.PcDimensiune == null
                        ? null
                        : (from pcd in allProductsWithDimensions
                            where pcd.IdProdus == pc.Produs.IdProdus && pcd.IdDimensiune == pc.PcDimensiune.IdDimensiune
                            select pcd.PretRedus).First(),
                    PerdeaEstePerecheDto = pc.PcDimensiune == null ? null : pc.PcDimensiune.PerdeaEstePereche,
                    TipGalerieCusaturaDto =
                        pc.PcManopera == null ? null : pc.PcManopera.TipGalerieLaManopera.NumeTipGalerie,
                    PretTipGalerieCusaturaDto =
                        pc.PcManopera == null ? null : pc.PcManopera.TipGalerieLaManopera.PretTipGalerie,
                    TipLinieCusaturaDto = pc.PcManopera == null ? null : pc.PcManopera.TipLinieLaManopera.NumeTipLinie,
                    PretTipLinieCusaturaDto =
                        pc.PcManopera == null ? null : pc.PcManopera.TipLinieLaManopera.PretPeTipLinie,
                    InelePrindereDto = pc.PcManopera == null ? null : pc.PcManopera.InelPrindereLaManopera!.CuloareInel,
                    PretInelPrindereDto = pc.PcManopera == null
                        ? null
                        : pc.PcManopera.InelPrindereLaManopera!.PretPerMetruInele,
                    MaterialDto = pc.PcManopera == null ? null : pc.PcManopera.MaterialLaManopere.NumeMaterial,
                    PretMaterialDto = pc.PcManopera == null ? null : pc.PcManopera.MaterialLaManopere.PretMaterial,
                })
                .ToListAsync();

The problem arises here:
 PretDto = pc.PcDimensiune == null
                        ? null
                        : (from pcd in allProductsWithDimensions
                            where pcd.IdProdus == pc.Produs.IdProdus && pcd.IdDimensiune == pc.PcDimensiune.IdDimensiune
                            select pcd.Pret).First(),
 PretRedusDto = pc.PcDimensiune == null
           ? null
                        : (from pcd in allProductsWithDimensions
                            where pcd.IdProdus == pc.Produs.IdProdus && pcd.IdDimensiune == pc.PcDimensiune.IdDimensiune
                            select pcd.PretRedus).First(),

This is the ProduseCuComenzi with all the details:
public class ProduseCuComenzi
{
    // Attributes
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int IdProduseCuComenzi { get; set; }
    public int NrBucati { get; set; }
    // Fk
    public int? IdSet { get; set; }
    public Seturi? Set { get; set; }
    public int IdProdus { get; set; }
    public Produse Produs { get; set; } = null!;
    public int IdComanda { get; set; }
    public Comenzi Comanda { get; set; } = null!;
    public int IdCuloare { get; set; }
    public Culori PcCuloare { get; set; } = null!;
    public int? IdDimensiune { get; set; }
    public Dimensiuni? PcDimensiune { get; set; } 
    public int? IdManopera { get; set; }
    public Manopere? PcManopera { get; set; }
    

}

This is the Dimensions class:
public class Dimensiuni 
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int IdDimensiune { get; init; }

    [StringLength(4)] 
    public string Lungime { get; init; } = null!;
    
    [StringLength(4)]
    public string Latime { get; init; } = null!;

    public bool? PerdeaEstePereche { get; set; }
    
    [StringLength(15)]
    public string? RecomandarePat { get; set; }
    // navigation props
    public ICollection<ProduseCuDimensiuni>? DProduseCuDimensiuni { get; }
    public ICollection<AsociereSeturi>? DAsociereSeturi { get; }
    public ICollection<ProduseCuComenzi>? DProduseCuComenzi { get; }

And this is the JOIN TABLE ProduseCuDimensiuni where i have the Price and the DiscountPrice:
public class ProduseCuDimensiuni
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int IdProdusCuDimensiune { get; init; }
    
    // Foreign Keys
    public decimal Pret { get; set; }
    public decimal PretRedus { get; set; }
    public int? IdDimensiune { get; set; }
    public Dimensiuni? PdDimensiune { get; set; } 
    public int IdProdus { get; set; }
    public  Produse  PdProduse { get; set; } = null!;}

What to do here to get the Pret and PretRedus and to avoid the error ? Do i need to use a JOIN between ProduseCuDimensiuni and ProduseCuComenzi ?
FINAL UPDATE!!!
SOLUTION(a bit overkill but i cannot find anything else)

PretDto =  ord.PcDimensiune.DProduseCuDimensiuni!
                            .First(pd => pd.IdDimensiune == ord.PcDimensiune.IdDimensiune &&
                                         pd.IdProdus == ord.Produs.IdProdus).Pret,
                        PretRedusDto = ord.PcDimensiune.DProduseCuDimensiuni!
                            .First(pd => pd.IdDimensiune == ord.PcDimensiune.IdDimensiune &&
                                         pd.IdProdus == ord.Produs.IdProdus).PretRedus,

Had a navigation prop in Dimensiuni related to the ProduseCuDimensiuni . Used that to get the price.

First thing to try: remove all null checks. They're not necessary because the entire statement is translated into SQL and SQL doesn't have null reference exceptions.

If you just want to avoid the error. Move the Select after ToListAsync. Be aware that this will move the load of that linq query to your application server instead of the DB. Now your error probably comes from the fact that you have materialized (retrieved all of the data) for allProductsWithDimensions  try to keep it an IQueryable.

@Irwene , this is for the admin page strict , it will not be loaded frequently . this is a way tho.

As for @GertArnold , i 'd like to keep them because the IDE gives warnings and it s more clear to me ,as i think that is not the problem

Ignore these IDE warnings. Look at what these checks do to the generated query. They have a very detrimental effect on the query plan. Anyway, now you added that allProductsWithDimensions is a local list, it's clear why EF doesn't translate it. Can't you add a navigation property to Produse in order to access allProductsWithDimensions by a navigation?

@Irwene The problem is that if i move the select after ToListAsync() the navigation props are not loaded . and i need to write a whole bunch of code to get the data which is not my ideal way , but i will keep the ideea in mind in case i dont fing any other answer.

@GertArnold The problem is that allProductsWithDimension is a JOIN table . That will not work out good , I'm really not sure.

@GertArnold Now i understand when you said "local list". It is not loaded in the context and that s why i get the error . Now i understood! Trying to get past that . If i find a way i will come back with the solution!

SOLUTION:
PretDto =  ord.PcDimensiune.DProduseCuDimensiuni!
                            .First(pd => pd.IdDimensiune == ord.PcDimensiune.IdDimensiune &&
                                         pd.IdProdus == ord.Produs.IdProdus).Pret,
                        PretRedusDto = ord.PcDimensiune.DProduseCuDimensiuni!
                            .First(pd => pd.IdDimensiune == ord.PcDimensiune.IdDimensiune &&
                                         pd.IdProdus == ord.Produs.IdProdus).PretRedus,

Had a navigation prop in Dimensiuni related to the ProduseCuDimensiuni . Used that to get the price.

Your answer looks good as it is, but, whenever sharing code snippets, it's recommended to change names of variables/properties to English in order to make it clearer. Unless, of course, you're dealing with the same specific library as the asker, and it contains non-english names.
